# Subset using loop over data frame in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataframe which has 50 variables for values 1-5, but some of them contains values more than 5 like 18656, I need to remove all these values from the dataframe. Is there a function which can do this.

I am using this code

```
func <- function(df_likert, col){
  df_likert <- subset(df_likert, col <= 5)
}

for (i in names(df_likert)) {
  func(df_likert, i)
}
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of your data? Just a few rows and columns that can help illustrate your question.

Comment: You want to remove the specif values or the whole rows? If it's the values, then you have to replace them with something in order to keep the correct dimensions in your dataframe. Are you replacing them with NA? With another value maybe?

Comment: all rows maybe, that can work

Comment: You are doing a study using the  Likert scale. There are groups (dimensions) of questions that will be averaged to get the score for each dimension.  You will just take the average for each group without the invalid response.   If more than, say two responses are invalid, the dimension cannot be calculated for that respondent.   This is what you need to explain in the question.

Comment: @HarlanNelson, I want to do the same, just doing it step by step, can you suggest me.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/likert/likert.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

# example dataset
dt = data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                x2 = c(3,3,4,5,10),
                x3 = c(10,1,1,2,3))

# original dataset
dt

#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  1  3 10
# 2  2  3  1
# 3  3  4  1
# 4  4  5  2
# 5  5 10  3

# update dataset
dt %>%
  mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(x > 5, NA, x)) %>%
  na.omit()

#   x1 x2 x3
# 2  2  3  1
# 3  3  4  1
# 4  4  5  2
```

This solution removes all rows with values more than 5, as you mentioned. If you exclude the `na.omit` part you can just replace those values with `NA` instead of removing the whole row.